# Solution's definition PDE - Characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, characteristics

> Solve
> $$\label{eq_0}\tag{1}\begin{cases}
> \partial_tu + (x-1) \partial_xu = 0\\
> u(0,x) = x^3
> \end{cases}$$
> in the plane region $Q : = \{(t,x) \in \Bbb R^2 : x<1\}$

Using characteristic I found
$$\label{eq_1}\tag{2}\begin{cases}
\dot t = 1\\
\dot x = x-1
\end{cases}$$
so we have that for this ODE system the following characteristic curve: $\xi\in \Bbb R$
$$(x-1)\cdot e^{-t} = \xi\label{eq_2}\tag{3}$$
Using initial condition knowing from above that our solution has to be in the form $u(t,x) = f(\xi)$, I compute
$$u(t,x) = [(x-1) e^{-t}+1]^3$$
I've checked via derivation that the solution and it looks alright. Here's the issue, in computing $\eqref{eq_2}$ via $\eqref{eq_1}$ in the calculation appears $\ln(x-1)$ that is defined for $x>1$ clearly in contrast with the request in $\eqref{eq_0}$. Is the solution unacceptable? The issues is that actually computing the integral should be $\ln|x-1|$? Thank you for the help!

---

**Edit-** Solving $\eqref{eq_1}$ :
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = x-1\\
\frac{dx}{x-1} = dt \\
\int \frac{dx}{x-1} = \int dt \\
\ln(x-1) = t + c \\
x-1 = e^t\cdot \xi$$

Comment: Well, you didn't show us how you solved (2)! But if you used separation of variables, then when you calculate $\int \frac{dx}{x-1}$ you should indeed get $\ln|x-1|$ (or $\ln(1-x)$ if you focus only on the region $x<1$). On the other hand, if you use an integrating factor instead, the problem never even arises in the first place.

Comment: @HansLundmark  I add the missing part, could you elaborate a little bit why integrating factor don't generate the problem? thank you

Comment: Are you familiar with the method of integrating factors to begin with? Your ODE $\frac{dx}{dt} - x = -1$ is a first-order linear ODE, so the method applies. (Multiply the equation by $e^{-t}$, use the product rule for derivatives backwards on the LHS, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can verify the answer does solve the PDE, and it is clearly well defined over the region Q, then the solution should be acceptable regardless on how you got there.